# Maya command not return reference list from *.ma

Tags: python, reference, maya, mel

In Maya I execute command to get the list for references included in the file:

```
cmds.file(fileName, q=True, reference=True)
```

It returns a list of the first level for references. And there is already a problem. If the file has an extension *.mb - then everything comes back. But if the file is saved as a *.ma - the command returns an empty list

I tried to run the command on MEL - the same result. I suspect that it is necessary to specify what that additional flags, but nothing like this in the documentation can not be found.

Tell me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

use [referenceQuery](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/referenceQuery.html) instead if you just want information about what is referenced from the file

Comment: referenceQuery return data from opened file! i'm not open file... i ask a reference list from maya file without open it...

Answer (score 0):

which maya version is the .ma file in compare to the main session where the "cmds.file(fileName, q=True, reference=True)" command will call

Comment: on all computers installed Maya 2016 from a single distribution. so that all the files were made in one version of the program